# Changing default naming strategy in hibernate.cfg.xml file

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to change the default naming strategy in hibernate.cfg.xml without success :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    ...
    <property name="cfg.namingStrategy">com.kestuboof.util.LowercaseNamingStrategy</property>
```

My strategy is never call.

Answer (score 0):

The naming convention of database objects and schema elements is controlled by the used implementation of the org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy interface. Hibernate 3.6 has four implementations of this interface:

**org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultComponentSafeNamingStrategy
org.hibernate.cfg.DefaultNamingStrategy
org.hibernate.cfg.EJB3NamingStrategy
org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy**

I decided to create a custom naming strategy by extending it and overriding its classToTableName() method. The source code of my implementation is given in following:

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy;

public class CustomNamingStrategy extends ImprovedNamingStrategy {

    private static final String PLURAL_SUFFIX = "s";


    @Override
    public String classToTableName(String className) {
        String tableNameInSingularForm = super.classToTableName(className);
        return transformToPluralForm(tableNameInSingularForm);
    }

    private String transformToPluralForm(String tableNameInSingularForm) {
        StringBuilder pluralForm = new StringBuilder();

        pluralForm.append(tableNameInSingularForm);
        pluralForm.append(PLURAL_SUFFIX);

        return pluralForm.toString();
    }
}
```

The next step is to configure the Hibernate to use my custom naming strategy. If you are using Hibernate, you can either

You can set a reference to the custom naming strategy by calling the setNamingStrategy() method of the Configuration class as described in the Implementing a Naming Strategy Section of the Hibernate Reference Documentation.

You can set the value of hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy property to CustomNamingStrategy in the Hibernate XML configuration file as described in the XML Configuration Section of the Hibernate Reference Manual.

If you are using JPA, you can set the used naming strategy by setting the value of hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy property to CustomNamingStrategy in the persistence.xml

Comment: I am more interested in the second part of your answer.
Do you propose to add this line to hibernate.cfg.xml file ?
<property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">com.kestuboof.util.LowercaseNamingStrategy</property>